How can i Return the Answer in the Enstein Chat bot from Knowledge search?
The Einstein bot only uses Summary to show articles in the chatbot.
I'm looking for a solution to return the full Answer either by test or attached PDF or word.
Is that possible? can I do it with Apex?
can you give me some references or resources to help me?
Thanks,
